# Getting "IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence" and do not know why my sequenceis empty

Tags: python, list, if-statement, random

This is the full code
The program is supposed to be something akin to a secret santa generator. Person a gives x number of gifts, persin b gives y number of gifts, and they don't get their own back.
The problem is I only have very basic experiance with python, and this happened.

```
import random
number_of_people=int(input("How many participants?"))
list_of_names=[]
list_of_numbers=[]
origional_list_to_use=[]
for i in range (number_of_people):
    name=input("What is the name of person "+str(i+1)+"?")
    number=int(input("How many is "+name+" giving?"))
    list_of_names.append(name)
    list_of_numbers.append(number)
    for i in range (number):
        origional_list_to_use.append(name)
list_to_use=origional_list_to_use
count=0
while count<number_of_people:
    giving=[]
    for i in range (list_of_numbers[count]):
        giving.append(random.choice(list_to_use))
    if list_of_names[count] not in giving:
         print(list_of_names[count]," gives to ",giving)
         count=count+1
         print(list_to_use)
         for giving in list_to_use:
             list_to_use.remove(giving)
    else:
         print("INVALID")
         count=0
         list_to_use=origional_list_to_use
```

gives an error, but why is my sequence empty? What am I doing wrong here?
I'm thinking it may be in my list or use of random?

Sorry, here is the full error bit.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/Documents/Test.py", line 18, in <module>
    giving.append(random.choice(list_to_use))
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 290, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: Could you add the full error and the line number to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace. I can tell you that this assignment `list_to_use=origional_list_to_use` does not do what you think it does. When you mutate `list_to_use`, you are also mutating `original_list_to_use`. To make a copy of the values of the list, you can do something like `list_to_use = [*original_list_to_use]`

Comment: Python will also not be happy with `for giving in list_to_use: list_to_use.remove(giving)` because you are modifying a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: Can you tell me what your program does?

Comment: @AnnZen I added the description

Comment: @DragonBobZ I added what the full error message was.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the sample data that resulted in this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appeared to be a couple of issues. I have addressed them with comments below:

```py
import random
number_of_people=3
list_of_names=[]
list_of_numbers=[]
origional_list_to_use=[]
for i in range (number_of_people):
    name=input("What is the name of person "+str(i+1)+"?")
    number=int(input("How many is "+name+" giving?"))
    list_of_names.append(name)
    list_of_numbers.append(number)
    for i in range (number):
        origional_list_to_use.append(name)

# prevent mutation of original_list_to_use by
# creating a copy instead of a reference
list_to_use=[*origional_list_to_use]
count=0
while count<number_of_people:
    # you use the name giving later in this block, you can't use that name here
    # giving = []
    giving_list = []
    for i in range (list_of_numbers[count]):
        giving_list.append(random.choice(list_to_use))
    if list_of_names[count] not in giving_list:
         # maybe not what you wanted?
         print(list_of_names[count]," gives to ", giving_list)
         count=count+1
         print(list_to_use)
         for giving in list_to_use:
             list_to_use.remove(giving)
    else:
         print("INVALID")
         count=0
         # do not mutate origional_list_to_use
         list_to_use=[*origional_list_to_use]
```

Answer (score 0):

If each participant can give multiple gifts to the same person, you can use

```
import random

number_of_people = int(input("How many participants? "))
names = numbers = gifts = list()

for i in range(number_of_people):
    name = input(f"What is the name of person {i+1}? ")
    number = int(input(f"How many is {name} giving? "))
    names.append(name)
    numbers.append(number)

for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
    choices = [n for n in names if n != name] # Define a list of all the participants this participant can give to
    giving = [random.choice(choices) for _ in range(number)] # Randomly pick a participant from the list *number* times
    print(f'{name} is giving {giving}')
```

If each participant can give at most one gift to the same person, you can use

```
import random

number_of_people = int(input("How many participants? "))
names = numbers = gifts = list()

for i in range(number_of_people):
    name = input(f"What is the name of person {i+1}? ")
    number = int(input(f"How many is {name} giving? "))
    names.append(name)
    numbers.append(number)

for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
    choices = [n for n in names if n != name]
    if number > len(choices): # The participant won't be able to give more than the maximum to be received
        print('INVALID')
        continue
    random.shuffle(choices) # Randomly shuffle the list
    giving = choices[:number] # Take *number* names from the list
    print(f'{name} is giving {giving}')
```

Input:

```
How many participants? 4
What is the name of person 1? Jannet
How many is Jannet giving? 3
What is the name of person 2? Bobby
How many is Bobby giving? 1
What is the name of person 3? Symone
How many is Symone giving? 2
What is the name of person 4? Timmy
How many is Timmy giving? 3
```

Output:

```
Jannet is giving ['Symone', 'Bobby', 'Bobby']
Bobby is giving ['Timmy']
Symone is giving ['Timmy', 'Bobby']
Timmy is giving ['Bobby', 'Bobby', 'Jannet']
```